# Flatten a Dictionary using Yield

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

My code is as follows:

```
def und1(d):
    for i in d:
        if type(d[i])==dict:
             und1(d[i])
        else:
            yield({i:d[i]})
Dict1 = {1: 'Geeks', 2: 'For', 3: 'Geeks',4:{5:'wevcn '}}
for z in  und1(Dict1):
    print(z)
```

I am currently getting output:

```
{1: 'Geeks'}
{2: 'For'}
{3: 'Geeks'}
```

Expected output:

```
    {1: 'Geeks'}
     {2: 'For'}
    {3: 'Geeks'}
    {5:'wevcn'}
```

Issue: My function is not calling recurisve function it is returning null. Can some tell me why?

Comment: You're calling `und1(d[i])` but you want to `yield from` instead

Comment: It is calling it. It returns a generator, which you immediately discarded

Comment: @Grismar  I f I use yeild from it gives 5 but I need {5:'wencn'} , That why iwanted to send d[i] as a recursive function

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why is getting discarded? I am expecting it to call recursively until last nested dictionary

Comment: You *did call it recursively*. You did nothing with the result of that recursive call, so the generator that was returned was discarded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should use `yield from` and can be simplified like this:

```
def und1(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from und1(v)
        else:
            yield {k: v}


dict1 = {1: 'Geeks', 2: 'For', 3: 'Geeks', 4: {5: 'wevcn '}}
for z in und1(dict1):
    print(z)
```

The `isinstance()` is specifically useful to check if "something is a ..." and by iterating over `.items()` of a `dict`, you can easily get access to both the key and value, so you don't have to index the `dict` again.

The output:

```
{1: 'Geeks'}
{2: 'For'}
{3: 'Geeks'}
{5: 'wevcn '}
```

In your code, a generator was returned from the function (as it does yield for non-dict items) and since you called the function, but didn't assign the function result to anything, that generator got discarded.

You could assign the function result to a variable and iterate over that, but there's no need for what you want with it.